# Task manager requiring elevation for regular users in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uac, task-manager

Run into a little bit of a snag with Windows 10, and it's a fairly well known one - the problem is that I'm struggling to find a Windows 10 compatible fix that actually works!

It's the old "regular users have to input their password to load task manager" chestnut again. How, exactly, do I work around this? Seeing as that inputting any valid credentials in gives you access to the task manager, I don't see why this is needed. I've mucked around with the UAC GPOs to try and get it to work, but that hasn't helped. I've also tried to start task manager with Windows, which in itself would be ideal as I can do that without elevation - but I can't see how to start it minimized, as everything I've seen simply doesn't take effect.

Any solutions would be much appreciated. As to why our users need task manager; well, Microsoft Office likes to tie itself in knots every now and again. It's much better for everyone's productivity to be able to actually kill the rogue tasks themselves!

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can log onto Windows 10 with a standard (non admin user) and Task Manager opens just fine (?).

Comment: I know, that's what it _should_ be doing. But for whatever reason, probably an old GPO somewhere, we don't get that - it prompts for a password if you're not an admin!

Comment: What password does it prompt for? Is it a UAC prompt? (Please be more specific.)

Comment: It is a UAC prompt, yes. It asks for admin details, but in fact it is actually just fine with any user, as long as the details are correct. Interestingly enough, I've only observed this behaviour on our Windows 10 Anniversary edition computers - the one remaining on version 1511 (which has a broken taskbar... still) worked just fine, even with the same GPOs!

Comment: Build a brand new Windows 10 machine, do not join it to a domain, and update it fully. Do you see the behavior? If not, then you know the behavior is likely caused by one of the GPO settings.

Comment: A new Windows 10 machine off the domain indeed does not show those settings - but then, nor does a pre-Anniversary edition one on it, from what I saw. Most odd!

Comment: Correct. This means that you are going to need to track this one down on your own. We can't do it from afar for you since we don't have access to the computer in question and we cannot see your screen.

Comment: I wasn't expecting that, I was hoping someone who had experienced something similar - and from a Google search, we're not the only ones, although there are few Windows 10 fixes out there - could provide me with some clues.

Comment: "I was hoping someone...could provide me with some clues" - I believe I did that. You will need to do some detective work to figure out what policy or setting is causing the behavior. Once you figure it out, you can write the answer here for the benefit of others.

Comment: I have exaclty the same problem with Win 10 1607, 1703 and the leatest technical preview.  Tomorrow I'll review my GPOs.

Comment: This is happening to me - it started somewhat randomly, any domain creds work, and I don't know what changed. To make things stranger, I have multiple PCs and it's only happening on one. My guess is that something doesn't have non-elevated access to something on one PC, which makes me suspect Registry perms

Comment: Are your users local administrators?

Comment: This happens if you have added current user to "Network Operators" group. And I don't know the workaround other than removing the user from there.

Answer (score 1):

Run this, and logoff/on

```
setx.exe __COMPAT_LAYER runAsInvoker
```

If you have Admin rights and run this then some commands [e.g. gpedit.msc] will no longer auto-elevate and you will need to "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Didn't work on W10_1803

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found the solution to this. Props go to a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/7j3qjy/windows_10_task_manager_triggers_uac/dr4nvoe/).

The issue is with the group policy "load and unload device drivers". Computer configuration -> Policies -> windows settings -> security settings -> local policies -> user rights assignment -> load and unload device drivers.

if this is set to a group the limited user is a member of (everyone, domain users, etc) then the prompt is displayed. if you set it instead to Administrators, the prompt is suppressed and everything works fine. I am not sure the ramifications of changing this value as it has been set for us since time immemorial. Seems to have to do with accepting unsigned device drivers. If everything suddenly stops working then i will have to set it back, but the setting goes all the way back to win2k so it may no longer be relevant (except to F up my shiz)...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem for past 4 months. I used to be a domain admin and removed that from my daily account. It was driving me mad getting UAC prompted for basic tasks like you mentioned. I finally took a deeper look at my group memberships. The key for me was looking at indirect (nested) memberships (I used Adaxes to do so, not sure best way to do so using standard AD tools). My account was a member of Group Policy Creator Owners. After removing that, doing gpupdate and finally a reboot I was able to launch stuff like Event Viewer, Task Manager, etc without the UAC prompt!!